# Add text on image at specific point using imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I want to add text on an image at specific point and want it be centre aligned. How can I specify to margin from top? I want to specify margin in pixels/inches from top.

Currently I am using this command:

```
 convert temp.jpg -gravity Center  -pointsize 30 -annotate 0 'Love you mom' temp1.jpg
```

it is writing text in centre of image. I want text to move to top.

This is what I am getting:
[image]

This is what i want:
[image]

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Try using `-gravity North` (this will move your text to the top of the image) and then adding an offset (`-annotate +0+100`) to move down your text:

```
convert temp.jpg -gravity North -pointsize 30 -annotate +0+100 'Love you mom' temp1.jpg
```

Answer (score 24):

Instead, you can use **-draw** to specify the location you want your text.

For example:

```
convert -font helvetica -fill white -pointsize 60 -gravity center -draw "text 0,300 'TEXT TO BE DISPLAYED'" /image_address/Image_input.png /image_address/Image_output.png
```

In this case, 0 is de x coordinate and 300 is the y coordinate, however the x coordinate is not really important since the **-gravity center** is already there.

Remember that the coordinate 0,0 is the top left corner.

Comment: Worth noting that `-font <param>` can take the full path to a `.ttf` file.

Answer (score 12):

```sh
convert -pointsize 40 -fill blue -draw 'text 600,600 "Love You Mom"' temp1.jpg temp2.jpg
                                              ^   ^
                                              |   |
                                        From Left |
                                                From Top
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: The only straight to the point answer. Could even compromise to `-draw 'text X, Y "Love You, Mom"'`

Comment: looks like `-draw` is more or less deprecated by `-annotate`,
see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55469545/difference-between-caption-draw-annotate-label-while-adding-text-to-imagemagi#answer-55470441) on another question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to add text on an image. Here is the answer using `Magick.NET` using `C#`:

1. Using the `Annotate()` function:

   ```
   image.Annotate(someText, new MagickGeometry(x, y, width, height), Gravity.Center)
   ```
2. Using a combination of `Composite` function and `new MagickImage("caption:...")` functionality. You can basically overlay an image on top of another image. You can create a *text caption image* which will be placed on top of the original image:

   ```
   MagickReadSettings readSettings = new MagickReadSettings()
   {
      Font = someFont,
      Width = 868,
      Height = 180,
      TextGravity = Gravity.North
   };
   using (var overlayImage = new MagickImage("caption:" + someText, readSettings))
   {
       originalImage.Composite(overlayImage, Gravity.South, x, y);
   }
   ```
3. Using `DrawableText` you can draw text anywhere on the image:

   ```
   DrawableTextAlignment centerAligned = new DrawableTextAlignment(TextAlignment.Center);
   DrawableText drawableText = new DrawableText(x, y, someText);
   image.Draw(drawableText, centerAligned);
   ```