# Difference between caption, draw, annotate, label while adding text to ImageMagick

Tags: text, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, caption, annotate

I'm trying to add text to an image using ImageMagick. I see multiple examples using draw, label, caption, annotate et al.
What is the difference between the above? 
I am able to test the results of the above commands with CLI, however am facing trouble when trying to run by java using IM4java.
Any help with java code snippets will be useful.

Answer (score 19):

Here is how I perceive it - it is quite opinionated and others are welcome to edit and add their insights.

---

`label:` Like other operators that contain a colon (`:`), e.g. `gradient:`, `xc:`, `logo:`, the `label:` operator generates its own canvas. That means you don't draw/type text onto an existing image, but rather you just draw/type your text and it creates a background for that text to sit on.

If you specify `-size` beforehand, it will create a canvas that size and put the text on it at the biggest pointsize that fits. So, let's try a wide, fixed size:

```
convert -background black -fill white -gravity center -size 800x100 label:'Stack Overflow' text.png
```

[image]

And also a narrow, fixed size:

```
convert -background black -fill white -gravity center -size 100x100 label:'Stack Overflow' text.png
```

[image]

If you don't specify `-size` beforehand, it will create the text at the point-size you ask for and put it on a suitably sized canvas. So, let's try a small pointsize without a canvas size:

```
convert -background black -fill white -gravity center -pointsize 16 label:'Stack Overflow' text.png
```

[image]

And also a large point-size without a canvas size:

```
convert -background black -fill white -gravity center -pointsize 64 label:'Stack Overflow' text.png
```

[image]

You can also specify just the width but no height, e.g. with `-size 200x`, or just the height but not the width, e.g. `-size x50`, and it will use the largest font it can but be constrained in the dimension you specify.

The following should give you an idea of which attributes of the text you can affect:

```
convert -background black -fill yellow -strokewidth 2 -stroke magenta \
    -undercolor blue -size 400x100 -gravity center -font 'AppleChancery' label:'Stack Overflow' text.png
```

[image]

---

`caption:` is like `label:` but it also does word wrapping so it will spread a long sentence across multiple lines for you all on its own.

---

`pango:` is a reasonably sophisticated markup language resembling HTML, that allows you to change fonts, colours, bold, italic, subscripts, superscripts and other text features mid-sentence.

---

`-draw "text 10,10 'Your message'"` is somewhat deprecated but it allows you to draw onto an existing image at a specific location, such as the `10,10` shown above. Note that it has no colon (`:`) so you need to already have an image/canvas for it to draw into.

---

`-annotate` really supersedes `-draw`. Like `-draw`, you need to have a canvas/image already on which to draw, but then it allows you to position, shear and rotate your text more readily than with `-draw`.

---

Anthony Thyssen provides an excellent discussion of all of these things, and more [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#text_operators).

Comment: I have a follow up question. When using im4java to process text, it constantly throws the following exception : "Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file". Based on the results of "convert -debug configure -list font 2>&1 | grep -E "Searching|Loading", I have tried adding the type and ghostscript xmls to the different expected locations and it still does not pick up the font files. Any idea what is going wrong ?

Comment: I presume you have seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24701602/2836621 I know nothing of the `im4java` port, does it definitely run under your user-id? Or does it run as some web-user like Apache? If it actually runs as someone else, you'd need to put the custom config file under that user's HOME directory.