# Captions on multiple polaroid images with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

So I have several images on which I want to put a logo and afterwards I want to make polaroids. I tried this and it works but now I also want to put captions with the filename and the image resolution on every polaroid and this won't work. I hope you understand what I want to do as English is not my first language.

```
let a=0
for i in *.JPG; do
   let a=a+1;
   convert $i Logo.png -gravity SouthEast -geometry 600x380+50+50 -composite -caption "%c %f\\n%wx%h" -gravity center -pointsize 38 -bordercolor snow -background black +polaroid -resize 640x ./done/pictures-$a.png 
done
```

Comment: Caption: creates a new image. It does not write text onto an existing image. Use -annotate in place of caption: See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#annotate

Comment: There are some examples here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/55470441/2836621